# Basic code for sending a string with bluetooth communication

Tags: android, bluetooth

I will just write numbers in a `EditText` and send it as a string when pressing a button. I found this basic code. Can i use this one ?

```
public void sendmessageclicked(View view)
{
    try 
    {
        sendData();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) 
    { 
        showMessage("SEND FAILED");
    }   
}


private void sendData() throws IOException 
{
    String msg = ØTextbox.getText().toString();
    msg += "\r\n";          
}
```

Comment: Its just a name for my textbox "ØTextbox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a [share intent](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). Something like this:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share text using"));
```

Also have a look at [the official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) regarding use of Bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do i implement this code in my button ?. I need to send the data with pressing a button.

Comment: Put the lines of code from my answer into your sendData() method.

Comment: Did you try the example? If it worked then please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I have communication problem between my android phone and bluetooth cc2540 kit. I need to solve that part first before i can test it. I need to make that part first. I will be back